# How can I combine lines and bars with two y axes in the google chart api?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Using google docs, a colleague has created a plot similar to: [image: this one]

I'm trying to use Google charts api to replicate this chart, but I'm having issues as the Chart api does not seem to allow having two different y axes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy and I just didn't read the documentation correctly. You just specify the axes parameter in the configuration and it should just work.